# slideUp() and slideDown() not working properly in jQuery

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

Hi Friends seeking your help I am trying to develop simple `slideUp()` and `sldeDown()` which work when user click on perticular button who has class `.buyBtn` actuly I am opening a panel by clicking on this class. Now the problem is when I click on this button my panel slide down for  2 seconds as per my code but when i click on that button 5 to 6 times more the panel open ans close very fast without wait for 2 minuates its close i dont know what is the problem behing this you can see my code here [**http://jsfiddle.net/uVdb3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/uVdb3/)

Please help me guys feel free to comment .. Thank in advance .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
    $('.oneItem').stop().animate({
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/uVdb3/1/)

I'd suggest using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` on `$('.chart').children().slideUp`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/uVdb3/3/)

Comment: Its working now thanks a ton for your precious help now time to learn diffrence between `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`... thanks again